# AWS Lambda generates large size files to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Currently we are having a aws lambda (java based runtime) which takes a SNS as input and then perform business logic and generate 1 XML file , store it to S3.

The implementation now is create the XML at .tmp location which we know there is space limitation of aws lambda (500mb).

Do we have any way to still use lambda but can stream XML file to S3 without using .tmp folder?

I do research but still do not find solution for it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly load an object to s3 from memory without having to store it locally. You can use the [put object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) API for this. However, keep in mind that you still have time and total memory limits with lambda as well. You may run out of those too if your object size is too big.

Comment: You mean like I have entire XML content as String (in Java) and then put that object directly to S3?

Comment: as a byte string yes.

Comment: Thanks. So we still have 3000mb max for memory.

Comment: Do we have better solution for this use case so we don't have limitation on size of the XML output file

Comment: Yes. If you need more, you should look into an ec2 deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can split the file into chunks and don't require to update the beginning of the file while working with its end you can use [multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpListPartsJavaAPI.html) providing a ready to go chunk and then free the memory for the next chunk.

Otherwise you still need a temporary storage for form all the parts of the XML. You can use DynamoDB or Redis and when you collect there all the parts of the XML you can start uploading it part by part, then cleanup the db (or set TTL to automate the cleanup).